# INNER JOIN with SELECT STATEMENT ISSUE

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I hope someone can help as I have been trying to fix this for a while now and stuck on a really small issue.

With the query below I am principally trying to do the following:

SELECT all stock codes from an order.

Then, find all the locations each stock code is stored in the STOCK_LOCATIONS table.

Then, return one location from the STOCK_LOCATIONS table.

However, I need to cross reference the LOCATION_DATA table.
Each location in the LOCATION_DATA table has a column called PICK and contains either a Y or N. I would like to return the locations with a Y as the first choice, and N if none exists with a Y in the PICK column.

I effectively need to order the results in the Inner Join LOCATION_DATA query, but this isn't possible. I have tried adding a SELECT statement within the INNER JOIN (which I believe is probably the way to go), but failed to get it working.

Any advice is appreciated.
Many thanks in advance...

```
SELECT
    STOCK_LOCATIONS.*,
    LOCATION_DATA.*,
    STOCK_DATA.PHYSICAL,
    ORDER_DATA.ENTRY,
    ORDER_DATA.STOCK,
    ORDER_DATA.ORDER_QTY,
    (SELECT
        COUNT(STOCK_LOCATIONS.location)
        FROM STOCK_LOCATIONS 
        WHERE ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku
        GROUP BY STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku
        HAVING COUNT(STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku) > 1
    ) AS RowCount
FROM ORDER_DATA
INNER JOIN STOCK_DATA
    ON ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_DATA.STOCK_CODE             
INNER JOIN STOCK_LOCATIONS
    ON ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku
INNER JOIN LOCATION_DATA
    ON STOCK_LOCATIONS.location = LOCATION_DATA.location
WHERE ORDER_DATA.ORDER_REF = '21254'    
GROUP BY ORDER_DATA.STOCK
ORDER BY LOCATION_DATA.pick_order ASC
```

HERE IS SOME SAMPLE DATA

AND AN EXAMPLE OF THE DESIRED OUTPUT

```
STOCK_LOCATIONS     
sku         location    
123456      A1  
123457      A2  
123459      C1  
123456      B1  
123457      B2  


LOCATION_DATA       
location    pick    
A1          Y   
A2          Y   
B1          N   
B2          N   
C1          N   


STOCK_DATA      
STOCK_CODE  PHYSICAL    
123456      10  
123457      0   
123459      100 


ORDER_DATA      
ENTRY   STOCK       ORDER_QTY
1       123456      10
2       123457      2
3       123459      1


RETURN DATA     
STOCK_CODE  ENTRY   LOCATION    PICK    ORDER_QTY   PHYSICAL    
123456      1       A1          Y       10          10
123457      2       A2          Y       2           0
123459      3       C1          N       1           100
```

HERE IS AN UPDATED ATTEMPT THAT THROWS UP ERRORS RELATING TO UNKNOWN TABLES:

```
// OPTION 1

SELECT
    STOCK_LOCATIONS.*,
    LOCATION_DATA.*,
    STOCK_DATA.PHYSICAL,
    ORDER_DATA.ENTRY,
    ORDER_DATA.STOCK,
    ORDER_DATA.ORDER_QTY,
    (SELECT
        COUNT(STOCK_LOCATIONS.location)
        FROM STOCK_LOCATIONS 
        WHERE ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku
        GROUP BY STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku
        HAVING COUNT(STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku) > 1
    ) AS RowCount,
    (SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN dat1.pick IS NOT NULL THEN loc1.location
            ELSE loc2.location 
        END
    ) AS location

FROM ORDER_DATA
INNER JOIN STOCK_DATA
    ON ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_DATA.STOCK_CODE

LEFT JOIN STOCK_LOCATIONS loc1
    ON ORDER_DATA.STOCK = loc1.sku

LEFT JOIN LOCATION_DATA dat1
    ON loc1.location = dat1.location
    AND dat1.pick = 'Y'

LEFT JOIN STOCK_LOCATIONS loc2
    ON ORDER_DATA.STOCK = loc2.sku

LEFT JOIN STOCK_LOCATIONS dat2
    ON loc2.location = dat2.location
    AND dat1.pick = 'N'

WHERE ORDER_DATA.ORDER_REF = '".$_GET_q."'  
GROUP BY ORDER_DATA.STOCK
ORDER BY LOCATION_DATA.pick_order ASC

// OPTION 2

SELECT
    STOCK_LOCATIONS.*,
    LOCATION_DATA.*,
    STOCK_DATA.PHYSICAL,
    ORDER_DATA.ENTRY,
    ORDER_DATA.STOCK,
    ORDER_DATA.ORDER_QTY,
    (SELECT
        COUNT(STOCK_LOCATIONS.location)
        FROM STOCK_LOCATIONS 
        WHERE ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku
        GROUP BY STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku
        HAVING COUNT(STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku) > 1
    ) AS RowCount

FROM ORDER_DATA
INNER JOIN STOCK_DATA
    ON ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_DATA.STOCK_CODE

JOIN STOCK_LOCATIONS loc1
    ON ORDER_DATA.STOCK = loc1.sku

JOIN LOCATION_DATA dat1
    ON loc1.location = dat1.location 
    AND dat1.pick = CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT
        *
        FROM STOCK_LOCATIONS loc2
        JOIN LOCATION_DATA dat2
            ON loc2.location = dat2.location
            AND dat1.pick = 'Y'
        WHERE ORDER_DATA.STOCK = loc2.sku
    )
    THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END

WHERE ORDER_DATA.ORDER_REF = '".$_GET_q."'  
GROUP BY ORDER_DATA.STOCK
ORDER BY LOCATION_DATA.pick_order ASC

// OPTION 3

SELECT
    STOCK_LOCATIONS.*,
    LOCATION_DATA.*,
    STOCK_DATA.PHYSICAL,
    ORDER_DATA.ENTRY,
    ORDER_DATA.STOCK,
    ORDER_DATA.ORDER_QTY,

    (SELECT
        COUNT(STOCK_LOCATIONS.location)
        FROM STOCK_LOCATIONS 
        WHERE ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku
        GROUP BY STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku
        HAVING COUNT(STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku) > 1
    ) AS RowCount,

    (SELECT 
            STOCK_LOCATIONS.location
            FROM STOCK_LOCATIONS 
            INNER JOIN LOCATION_DATA
                ON STOCK_LOCATIONS.location = LOCATION_DATA.location
            WHERE ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku
            ORDER BY pick DESC, rand()
            LIMIT 1
    ) AS location

FROM ORDER_DATA

INNER JOIN STOCK_DATA
    ON ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_DATA.STOCK_CODE             

INNER JOIN STOCK_LOCATIONS
    ON ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku

INNER JOIN LOCATION_DATA
    ON STOCK_LOCATIONS.location = LOCATION_DATA.location

WHERE ORDER_DATA.ORDER_REF = '".$_GET_q."'  
GROUP BY ORDER_DATA.STOCK
ORDER BY LOCATION_DATA.pick_order ASC
```

Comment: Please include example data for each table, and the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could join the location table twice, once for rows with `pick = 'Y'` and once for rows with `pick = 'N'`.  Then you can use a case statement to prefer the first, but fall back on the second:

```
SELECT  case
        when dat1.pick is not null then loc1.location
        else loc2.location 
        end as Location
....
LEFT JOIN 
        STOCK_LOCATIONS loc1
ON      ORDER_DATA.STOCK = loc1.sku
LEFT JOIN
        LOCATION_DATA dat1
ON      loc1.location = dat1.location
        AND dat1.pick = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN
        STOCK_LOCATIONS loc2
ON      ORDER_DATA.STOCK = loc2.sku
LEFT JOIN
        LOCATION_DATA dat2
ON      loc2.location = dat2.location
        AND dat1.pick = 'N'
```

Another option is a join condition with a subquery.  The subquery could look for locations with `pick = 'Y'` when they exists, and fall back on `pick = 'N'` otherwise.

```
JOIN    STOCK_LOCATIONS loc1
ON      ORDER_DATA.STOCK = loc1.sku
JOIN    LOCATION_DATA dat1
ON      loc1.location = dat1.location 
        AND dat1.pick = case when exists
        (
        select  *
        from    STOCK_LOCATIONS loc2
        JOIN    LOCATION_DATA dat2
        ON      loc2.location = dat2.location
                AND dat1.pick = 'Y'
        WHERE   ORDER_DATA.STOCK = loc2.sku
        )
        then 'Y' else 'N' end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried option 2 but couldn't get it working. I wasn't sure where the first option would fit in the overall query. Could you possibly paste in your examples to the whole query from above so I can try both again? Many Thanks, and much appreciated...

Comment: I have tried option 1 again and I think I have it working. It is however saying that STOCK_LOCATIONS is an unknown table? I have checked the spelling and it does not make sense. Many Thanks, Joe

Comment: The code creates an alias for the table: `STOCK_LOCATIONS as loc1`.  In other parts of the query, the table is known as `loc1`, not `STOCK_LOCATIONS`.  That is essential if you use one table multiple times.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your help on this, but I must really be doing something wrong here. I have updated the original question with my attempt at both options. Could you possibly have a look and let me knnow what you think... Many Thanks, Joe

Comment: In the query you posted, `WHERE ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku` should probably be `WHERE ORDER_DATA.STOCK = CASE WHEN dat1.pick IS NOT NULL THEN loc1.location ELSE loc2.location END`

Comment: OK. This is taking ages to figure out. Thank you so much for your help, I'll let you know when I get it working. I have taken on board all your advice and will hopefully crack it today sometime. Thanks, Joe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this as a subquery in the select clause:

```
SELECT STOCK_LOCATIONS.*, LOCATION_DATA.*, STOCK_DATA.PHYSICAL,
       ORDER_DATA.ENTRY, ORDER_DATA.STOCK, ORDER_DATA.ORDER_QTY, 
       (SELECT COUNT(STOCK_LOCATIONS.location) 
        FROM STOCK_LOCATIONS  
        WHERE ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku   
        GROUP BY STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku  
        HAVING COUNT(STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku) > 1
       ) AS RowCount,
       (SELECT STOCK_LOCATIONS.location
        FROM STOCK_LOCATIONS  
        WHERE ORDER_DATA.STOCK = STOCK_LOCATIONS.sku
        order by pick desc, rand()
        limit 1
       ) AS ChosenLocation
```

This does a correlated subquery choosing one row.  It orders them to fit the business logic you want.  If you want more information about the location, I would put this into a subquery and join in the additional information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's really appreciated. This works to a certain extent, but it does not order correctly with the result as a whole. For example, the locations that have been overwritten are not ordered with the rest of the results, they are ordered as though the new select didn't happen, and the wrong pick = 'N' results were returned. Any ideas? Could I get this SELECT statement in the INNER JOIN statment that gets the locations?

Comment: @JoeLewis . . . Yes, you can place this in the inner joins.  I phrased this solution more as a suggestion, because I wasn't really clear which locations you want to output.  It looks like you have good SQL skills, and the hint of using a subquery in the SELECT should help you solve the problem.

Comment: OK. This is taking ages to figure out. Thank you so much for your help, I'll let you know when I get it working. I have taken on board all your advice and will hopefully crack it today sometime. Thanks, Joe.